# Yarn Job related commands

Tags: hadoop-yarn

For any job which is submitted to YARN using YARN console and YARN Cluster UI, how to find:

1. Who has submitted the job?
2. To which YARN queue is a job submitted?
3. How much time did it take to finish the job?

I tried using below command, but it gives lot of details, not specific
**yarn application -list**

Comment: You can check all the above-mentioned queries in Resource manager(RM) UI `http://<host where Resource manager is running>:8088`
or you can use specific yarn CMD from terminal : `yarn application -appStates RUNNING -list` or 
`$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop -job -status <jobid>` 
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerHA.html

Answer (score 0):

Give a look at Yarn Admin Page, there are the details about all the jobs you have submitted to the cluster.

Just accessing to `<Local_ip>:8088 I.E: Localhost:8088`.

Also, there is a section for logs at `/logs/userlogs` directory. This directory will contain logs for all applications running by a user.